# REST API - Best practice for "exists in"

Tags: java, api, rest

Let's say I have a classroom, and the classroom holds many students.
I would like to expose an API saying for each student what are his classrooms (student can have multiple classrooms).

The obvious API to expose is something like this:

```
GET https://my.app/api/students/{student_id}/classrooms
```

However - Since the classroom holds the students on my DB **I'll have to go to each classroom and check for it's students which could take a long time** (I could have millions of classrooms)

Since In my use case the user should already be familiar with the classrooms I would like to expose an *"exists in"* API. (and of course limit that list)

I've thought about two options and both kinda look counter-intuitive.

#### Option 1

```
GET https://my.app/api/students/{student_id}/classrooms?classrooms=1,2,3...
```

#### Option 2

```
GET https://my.app/api/students/{student_id}/classrooms
BODY- {"classrooms": [1,2,3...]}
```

Does any of the options is intuitive/make sense or alternatively is there any other option?

Comment: The spec for `GET` doesn’t support a request body, IIRC, so in practicality Option 2 likely wouldn’t be possible.

Comment: Hi @esqew - I've looked it up and as it is indeed not recommended , but the protocol does support `GET`  with body

Answer (score 2):

```
GET https://my.app/api/students/{student_id}/classrooms

{"classrooms": [1,2,3...]}
```

Out of bounds - I would immediately reject in a code review without reading further.  The problem here is that it is inconsistent with the *semantics* of GET as defined by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

In particular - by taking identifying information of the resource and moving it from the URI to the message body, you are, in effect, hiding that information from general purpose caches.  You would need an enormous compensating benefit to make that tradeoff worth while, and I don't see that compensation here.

> the protocol does support GET with body

Yes, but not in a useful way.  You are absolutely correct that the protocol permits GET with a body, see RFC 7230.

> Request message framing is independent of method semantics, even if the method does   not define any use for a message body.

But in the case of GET, the body doesn't *mean* anything; as far as a general purpose component is concerned, the body of a GET request is just noise.

```
GET https://my.app/api/students/{student_id}/classrooms?classrooms=1,2,3...
```

Better.  Here, you are compliant with the semantics of GET, the cache has all of the information needed to correctly store and fetch representations.

One thing to consider in your resource design: do you want to have a different document for every possible combination of classroom numbers, or do you want to have some smaller number of documents that are re-usable with different combinations of rooms.

It's a trade off: coarse grained resources allow your reads to better leverage caching, but also requires more work by client code.

That said:

> Since the classroom holds the students on my DB I'll have to go to each classroom and check for it's students which could take a long time

If this is an important problem, then perhaps you should design your data model to support it more organically (like being able to fetch classrooms by student id directly).